# File not Found in Project root folder

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-io, java.util.scanner

I run the following code and the program returns FileNotFoundException:

```
public void read()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/project_folder_name/data.in"));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

I have tried with the **data.in** file in the project root folder, in the package folder and in an arbitrary folder (i.e /User/.../Desktop/data.in) and I always get the same result:

Examples:

```
//relative path (for when data.in is within project root folder)
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.in"));

//path for when data.in is moved in package
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
new File("/project_folder_name/source_folder_name/package_name/data.in"));
```

Neither of these work.

I'm running the program in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: If your using windows you should be using \ not /

Comment: In Eclipse I believe I have to use / or else it returns error: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )`

Comment: Yes, using the forward slash (/) is correct. Even in Windows, Java resolves filepaths using the forward slash as the file-separator, and back-slashes (\) are used as the escape character, altering the meaning of the String.

Comment: You should escape \ by \\

Comment: Well you can escape the backslash and use it as the file separator, so I guess that is a solution, but I feel it's clearer and more universal to use the forward-slash, as this does indeed work on Windows as well as Unix.

Comment: You can provide the **full** file name with file path, e.g. `c:/project_folder/src/some/path/data.in`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use try/catch to avoid the exception from interrupting the program:

```
public void read()
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner
                    (new File("data.in"));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this case, this works also with:

```
"C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\data.in"
"/Users/.../Desktop/data.in"
"data.in"(if it's in the root folder)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is printed in each of these cases?

Comment: It printed what was written in data.in. In my case I just wrote something like: 1 2 3 4, and that's what it printed.

Comment: Yes, whichever "format" I use: Windows path, Eclipse path or relative path, if you can call it that.

Answer (score 0):

The path you pass to `new File()` is a filesystem path. The path you pass (`"/project_folder_name/data.in"`) is Eclipse path. The filesystem equivalent would be `${YOUR_WORKSPACE_LOCATION}/project_folder_name/data.in`, where ``${YOUR_WORKSPACE_LOCATION}` is the absolute filesystem path to your workspace location. How you get that into your test code is quite a question. If you can use Eclipse launchers, you can use ${resource_loc} Eclipse variable in the launcher's configuration.

Another alternative is to use relative path. When Eclips runs your test, the current working directory is project's root directory. So you you can use just `"data.in"`. Or better yet, use `"src/test/resources/data.in"` (for a Mavenized project).

Comment: I don't think this is a file path problem. After I used try/catch, it worked for existing files and no longer bumped into the FileNotFoundException before even checking whether the file exists or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows you should be using \ not /.  Also you can give absolute path ex. C:\folder\folder\data.in or you can just put the file in classpath and do File("data.in") or relative to class path File("\folder\data.in"). Don't forget to escape \ by 2 \.

Try putting the file in the root of your project folder and just do new File("data.in").
Copy and paste file to root folder in eclipse (project folder)

Change

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/project_folder_name/data.in"));
```

To

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data.in"));
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct... Java always uses '/' as a file separator in file paths. Putting '\'s in Strings like that will likely cause unwanted escaping of characters, and make the String invalid

Comment: Don't downvote until you have asked for an explanation

Comment: This works for me just tested you are doing something else wrong because you can specify absolute path or relative path(root folder of your project).

Comment: I also tried using \\. I don't get invalid escape sequence anymore. However, I still get FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I downvoted it because your initial answer was incorrect, using a single back-slash as the file delimiter causes escaping in the String-literal which invalidates the String, your updates have corrected that though.

Comment: I tried using relative path when data.in is within the project's root folder. It doesn't work..

Comment: @dannychris37 you should just use the absolute file-path to your file. Find your file on disk, and then input the absolute path to the file as the parameter to the `new File(file-path)`. It's likely that the home-directory of your Java executable is the directory in which your code is being run, therefore any relative-path supplied will be added to the path of your Java-home directory, and not the root directory of your project.

Comment: No it is the root directory of your project trust me or try it.  Don't speculate.

Comment: I made a copy of data.in in my Desktop. I then tried with `"/Users/.../Desktop/data.in"` and I get the same error.

Comment: Specify full path C:\\users\\...\\desktop\\data.in don't leave off drive specification.

Comment: Then you have another problem cause it works fine on my machine.